# GIt status says file is deleted but git rm says errror: pathspec '.....' did not match any files

Tags: git

I've done this 100s of times.
I deleted a file from a directory and then run git status which looks fine.

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    themes/custom/gitb/templates/views-view-field--field-overall-rating.tpl.php 
#
```

Then I run 
**git rm themes/custom/gitb/templates/views-view-field--field-overall-rating.tpl.php**
and receive an error message

```
error: pathspec 'themes/custom/gitb/templates/views-view-field--field-overall-rating.tpl.php' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

git status "knows" about the file but but git rm doesn't and won't remove it. I'm stuck and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 10):

A quick and dirty solution would be to add back the file and use

```
git rm themes/custom/gitb/templates/views-view-field--field-overall-rating.tpl.php
```

to remove it.

`git rm` removes the file from the filesystem too, so you don't need (and in general you shouldn't) to manually remove the file.

**EDIT**

A cleaner way to do so, would be to make git to notice the missing file using

```
git add -u
```

or

```
git commit -a
```

From the doc of `git-add`, here's the description of the `-u` option

> Only match  against already tracked files in the index
>   rather than the working tree. That means that it will never stage new
>   files, but that it will stage modified new contents of tracked files
>   and that **it will remove files from the index if the corresponding
>   files in the working tree have been removed.**

and here's the one for the `-a` option of `git-commit`

> Tell the command to **automatically stage files that have been modified
>   and deleted**, but new files you have not told git about are not
>   affected.

Comment: touch and remove didn't quite work but touch, add and then remove worked so thanks very much. I need to understand the difference between the "working tree" and the "index".

Comment: yeah probably the `touch` trick is too naive. I'll remove it from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [git rm man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html#_removing_files_that_have_disappeared_from_the_filesystem) describes several ways of removing files no longer present in the working tree.

In the future, it is simpler to delete the file with `git rm` than to delete it separately.

Answer (score 0):

this append when you remove the files an directories not using git's `git rm` command.

I did
     git stash

It restored the files 
that I had deleted using `rm` instead of `git rm`.

I fact I first did a checkout of the last hash, but I do not believe this is required.