# Remove weird 'Iconr' file from the repository

Tags: macos, git, atlassian-sourcetree

In my git repository I've got a weird file in the staging area that's refusing to be reverted, removed, committed - basically I can't make it *go away*..

The file must be some ancient OS 9 file sitting there in the folder for years.

Couple days ago I've removed the file in the file system so now git is tracking the deletion of `Iconr`.

However, it's stuck there.

The error I'm getting via SourceTree (my git UI client) is

> fatal: pathspec 'folder/Iconr' did not match any files

Any idea how to make git **completely forget** about that file?

Comment: The filename is probably really called `Icon\r` - maybe the UI client doesn't display it properly. The trailing line break can trip various tools but should be dealt with by git when called from the command line

Comment: @cacau Indeed, on the command line it said 'Icon\r'

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556250/how-to-ignore-icon-in-git

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is best to revert to the command line in order to have a more precise error message.

There you can try a `git add -u`, followed by a `git commit`, in order to register the deletion of that file in the repo.
See "[`git status` says file is deleted but `git rm` says `error: pathspec '…' did not match any files`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14444340/6309)" as an example.

You can also preview what a git clean would give: `git clean -d -x -n` (as explained in "[Why is there no “pathspec” when I try to remove a folder in Git?](https://superuser.com/a/431653/141)")

The other issue is when that file isn't tracked at all in your current branch, but is tracked in another branch. See [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15931542/6309) to check if that is the case.

Answer (score 34):

Adding a line

```
Icon?
```

to .gitignore worked for me.

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/167170/removing-invisible-icon-files-on-a-local-repository-on-a-mac

Comment: amplification: adding 'Icon?' to .gitignore causes 'Icon\r' to be ignored.  Since ? is a single character wild card, then names like Iconx, Icon1 will also be ignored.  However, 'Icon?' is simple to apply using any text editor ... and is sufficient for many use cases.

Comment: Add "Icon?" into .gitignore worked for me.

"Icon" or "Iconr" or "Icon\r" did not.

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted answer. Icon\r and several other variants are files OSX stuffs into directories to represent a custom folder icon. There are a number of similar variations, all of which have one extra character, but this answer covers all of them.

Answer (score 8):

The `Icon^M`-like files most likely are created by some external apps such as [*Folderol*](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/folderol/id796987992) which are highlighting your folders.

You should either remove the app which is doing that, or ignore it in your `.gitignore` file, e.g.

```
printf "Icon\r\r" >> .gitignore
```

<sup>This is a shell command. Or add it as `Icon??` or you can reproduce `^M` special character by <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.</sup>

Related: [How to ignore Icon? in git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17556250/55075)

If you don't want to commit this change into your repository, alternatively add it into your global `.gitignore` or add it into `.git/info/exclude`.

See: [Using Git / Ignoring files](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/).

To remove the files it-self, try:

```
find . -type f -name 'Icon?' -print -delete
```

Or if they're the only one which are unstaged, run: `git clean -f`.

Comment: One question mark worked for me
find . -type f -name 'Icon?' -print -delete

Answer (score 3):

As a general workaround the `.gitignore` file can be edited to completely ignore the `Icon\r` files as described in this blog entry:  [Git Tip: Ignoring Icon\r in .gitignore](http://blog.bitfluent.com/post/173740409/ignoring-icon-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 3):

What shows as "Iconr" in SourceTree is really `Icon\r` where `\r` is the hex value `0x0d`.

The .gitignore filename pattern matching is limited when compared to POSIX regex. Regular expression patterns such as `Icon\r` and `Icon\x0d` did not work for me with SourceTree.

**Simple Ignore:** Adding `Icon?` pattern in the .gitignore file will work to have "Iconr" files ignored in SourceTree.

*Caveat: `Icon?` uses `?` which is a single character wildcard. So, files and folders like `Icon\r`, "icona", "icon3" and "Icons" will be ignored with an `Icon?` pattern. If needed, use file names "Icon01", "icon02", "iconaa" instead of "Icon1", "icon2", "icona" with this workaround to add such files to git.*

**Precise Ignore:** The precise `Icon\r` filename can be ignored with a binhex editor.

In binhex editor, add `0a 49 63 6f 6e 0d 0d 0a` in the .gitignore file. The extra `0a`s are linefeeds to bracket the `Icon\r\r` for later editing of an otherwise unix file.

*Caveat: If using the precise value `49 63 6f 6e 0d`, be careful to not replace `\r` with `\n`. In other words, do not edit .gitignore in a text editor set to auto-replace line separators with this approach.*

*Note: The **Simple Ignore** `Icon?` is convenient and sufficient for most use cases.* Quit and restart SourceTree to see the changes take effect. macOS's git is case-insensitive by default.

**Custom Folder/File Icons:** An `Icon\r` file is created each time a custom icon is added to a folder or file. For example, the custom icon can be added via the "Get Info" window. Here is an example where the default system folder icon has been replaced with a custom folder icon:

[image: "Get Info" window]

The `Icon\r` file(s) can be removed manually via the file's/folder's "Get Info" window or by invoking a shell command to remove the `Icon\r` files, as noted in kenorb's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore the `Icon?` on any level of subfolders using wildcards:

```
// .gitignore
**/Icon?
```

Wildcards works since version 1.8.2 of git

Comment: You don't need globbing here. If you remove the leading `/` it will be searched recursively.