# Delete unnecessary Iconr files from the Xcode commit

Tags: xcode, git

I need to remove these Iconr files from the project\commit but I cant find them in the project folder (even in the hidden files).

I can't perform any commit with these files, how can I remove them?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove weird 'Iconr' file from staging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589978/remove-weird-iconr-file-from-staging)

Answer (score 0):

These files are created by some external apps such as [Folderol](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/folderol/id796987992) which are used for highlighting/coloring your folders. Remove that app, or add these files into gitignore files, either to:

- `.gitignore` inside your repository root,
- global `.gitignore`, e.g.

  ```
  git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore
  ```
- into explicit repository exclude file (`.git/info/exclude`) inside your repository root.

See: [Using Git / Ignoring files](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/)

To delete them, try:

```
find . -type f -name 'Icon??' -print -delete
```